# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] require() of ES Module not supported Nuxt Js 3

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, cpanel

i'm trying to use nuxt 3 for create a web app and it's work very fine on my desktop with the version 17.3.0 of node js but it's not the case on the server ...

it's a server with cpanel and i use the tools "setup node.js app" but i got this error every time.

```
App 37252 output: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:979
App 37252 output:     throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, true);
App 37252 output:     ^
App 37252 output: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/private/admin/server/index.mjs not supported.
App 37252 output: Instead change the require of /home/private/admin/server/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
App 37252 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 37252 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 37252 output:     at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
App 37252 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
App 37252 output:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
App 37252 output: }
```

in the "setup node.js app" tools, the latest version of node available is the 16.13.0 so i think the problem is from that (it's work fine on my computer with the version 17.3.0).

If it's that, how i can hade the latest version of nodeJs to cpanel ?

EDIT :

My package.json :

[image: My package.json]

my nuxt.config.ts :

[image: my nuxt.config.ts]

My app.vue

```
<template>
    <Html lang="fr">
        <Head>
            <Title>title</Title>
            <Meta name="description" content="My page's description" />
        </Head>
        <Body>
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <ion-icon name="grid-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Hub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Vérification</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <ion-icon name="build-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Modération</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <ion-icon name="chatbubble-ellipses-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Communication</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Paramètre</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <div class="indicator"></div>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <NuxtPage />
        </Body>
    </Html>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';


onMounted(() => {
    const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
    navItems.forEach(navItem =>
        navItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            navItems.forEach(item => {
                item.classList.remove('active');
            });
            navItem.classList.add('active');
        })
    );
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: local('Roboto'), url('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 10rem);
    height: 5rem;
    padding: 0 5rem;
    background: #039ce7;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

nav > ul {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

nav > ul > li > a > .icon {
    line-height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a > .icon {
    transform: translateY(-.5rem);
}

nav > ul > li.active > a > .icon {
    transform: translateY(-2.4rem);
    color: white;
}

nav > ul > li > a > .text {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateY(40px);
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a > .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(22px);
}

nav > ul > li.active > a > .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(22px);
}

nav .indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(-52% + -8px);
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #039ce7;
    border: 8px solid white;
    transition: .5s;
}

nav .indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    left: -20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 white;
}

nav .indicator::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    right: -20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 0 white;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator {
    left: 0;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 25%;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 75%;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(-150%);
    left: 100%;
}
</style>
```

My index.vue :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/hello');
</script>
```

An my hello.ts file :

```
export default async () => 'Hello World';
```

I'm at the start of my projects so i have only App.vue, Index.vue, and hello.ts

For deploy my app, i run `npm run deploy`, then i move all content of ".output" folder (the folder where the app is build) in the admin folder on my server (with filezilla).

.output folder :

[image: .output folder]

(any require is in the index.mjs file)

On my server, i launch the app with the "setup node.js app" tools.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `type: "module"` to your package.json file then delete your node_modules directory and do an `npm install` again.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer ! Unfortnaly it's not work,  i deleted node_modules folder and .output folder, i added type: "module" and i did an npm install && npm run build but i have exactly the same issue...

Comment: Are you using the require statement in your code? If so, you'll need to change it to import. Can you describe how you're deploying the nuxt app and how you're configuring cpanel to launch your node app? Please add this info to your original question.

Comment: it's up to date, again thanks for fast answer

Comment: Hmm, some things are confusing to me. It seems like the problem is an issue with cpanel -- not the node version. I don't see where the /path/index.mjs file is located in your files. The error message doesn't seem to point to your index.mjs file. Also, I don't see your deploy script in your package.json. If you run npm start do you see the error on your local system (vs running npm run dev)?

Comment: yes sorry the /path/index.mjs not exists actually because i did a lot of test and i forgot to update the post but now i have updated my original question and it is now the good path in the error (but always the same error). and when i run "npm run start" the only error i had it's about "ionicon" but i comments all about ionicon, deleted .output and rerun "npm run build", now i not have error with "npm run start" but still the same when i use cpanel...
And when i let the admin folder empty, cpanel create automatically an index.mjs file in, so the directory is forcedly good. (this file work)

Comment: You've done a lot of good documentation here, but I'm out of ideas. My hunch is that it's related to how cpanel is launching the server.

Comment: I am also short of idea, it's been a week that I'm looking for a solution, that's why I'm here ... I even try to launch my site with PM2 (which look work in terminal) but on the server, once PM2 launch I do not know how to redirect the user on it :/

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue ? I'm running into the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Grzegorz answer solve my problem. But you may need to edit the import for index.mjs in the src/app.mjs

```
import { default as handler } from './.output/server/index.mjs';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `node` preset while building Nuxt 3 App. You can use our Express.js wrapper to run the app using CloudLinux Passenger that is installed on your CPanel.

Check this out: https://github.com/Kodefix/express-wrapper-for-nuxt-3

CloudLinux Passenger can't handle ES Module, so you have to use `entry.js` as helper file to run the app. This is the easiest way to handle Nuxt 3 App on shared hosting, etc.